# App Inventor 2 emulator issue

Tags: app-inventor

Firstly sorry if this place does not deal with questions like this, I have tried the tutorials online for App Inventor and I cannot seem to find anything relevant.

Basically I am downloading App Inventor 2 which has given me no issues, however when I try and connect to the emulator it fails. It states that 'Your companion is out of date', the tutorials online told me for this I would have to download the latest software (which I already had but I uninstalled and tried again). After getting the same response a few times I managed to get through to another screen that stated 'Unable to send update through to device/emulator' and on the actual emulator it just states 'Parse error - There is a problem parsing the package'

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Try a Hard Reset from the Connect menu.  Then load the emulator again and follow the instructions EXACTLY. The new Companion is 2.24... the better place to ask is in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) or do a search there...

Comment: Thank you @Taifun for your suggestions. I have tried a hard reset but unfortunately it did not work. I will try and follow the instructions again and if this does not work I will pop over to the forum :). Thanks again.